# Keil 8051 STARTUP.A51 main function

Tags: c, program-entry-point, startup, keil, 8051

I have project created in Keil uVision. The source code has STARTUP.a51 assembly file with jump instruction to main(LJMP ?C_START). But source file(s) in the project doesn't have definition of main() function.

In this case, where how the control is transferred to application code? Is there a way to map custom function to C_START? how its done?
Note: the code works fine.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with keil project generation but normally _your_ source code has to define `main`. Otherwise, how does the code you wrote get control?

Answer (score 0):

I expect that C_START is the C runtime startup which initializes memory and then calls your main() function.  You could experiment and verify that your code runs.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't see main() defined anywhere in source files.